# How to restrict filesize for uploads?

Tags: php, file, upload, filesize

Please see the snippet below.  I am using it in a way to restrict files over 5 mb.  Whenever the file is above 5 mb it says that "The file you attempted to upload is not allowed" when in fact it should say "The file you attempted to upload is too large."  It's not that i placed them in the wrong part of the code, i am using:

```
if(filesize($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
```

Entire code:

```
// Configuration - Your Options
$allowed_filetypes = array('.pdf','.jpg','.png','.gif'); 
$max_filesize = 5242880; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
$upload_path = "/store/user/$user"; 
$filename = $_FILES['filename']['name']; 
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); 
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
// Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
if(filesize($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
// Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!is_writable($upload_path))
die('');
```

Comment: What happens when you upload a file which is _less_ then .5MB?

Comment: The best way should be to check size of the file on client side (but I don't know how, some js from google :-)). On server side you can simply set limit by ini_set/upload_max_filesize and check for errors...

Comment: @Fanda, I'm pretty sure that attempting to limit upload size in `ini_set` doesn't work very well.

Comment: @JMCCreative files less than .5mb get uploaded.

Comment: ini_set cannot be used to change upload settings. your code (and the ini_set) is NOT invoked until AFTER the upload has occured. Any upload settings changes must be at the php.ini/.htaccess level.

Comment: I agree about the `.htaccess`, but the question here is "Why is the code stopping at `die` one, instead of `die` two?

Comment: `var_dump(compact('ext', 'allowed_filetypes'))` to see if the `in_array` check *should* work to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filename extension code is not right, most likely.

Try with:

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
// ...
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// ...
```

Otherwise, the file is basically not uploaded due to filesize constraints; you can check this by looking at `$_FILES['filename']['error']`. The value should be 0.

If it's not 0, you can check here what it means: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

In your case, the file is probably too big; check here what could be wrong: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Comment: Then I would suggest you do a `var_dump($ext, $allowed_filetypes);` and show the results.

Comment: bool(false) array(4) { [0]=> string(4) ".pdf" [1]=> string(4) ".jpg" [2]=> string(4) ".png" [3]=> string(4) ".gif" } The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.

Comment: Okay, so the assignment to `$ext` has an issue .. you will have to `var_dump($filename);` as well then.

Comment: ok, doing that i got: NULL The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.

Comment: updated my answer; you're having another issue altogether ;-)